# Export Org-Mode tree just as is to PDF/HTML

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, pdf

Say if I have a org-mode document with `org-indent-mode` enabled. The document will look like the following in the Emacs buffer.

[image: Org-Mode buffer screenshot]

Is it possible to export this to a PDF or HTML that looks exactly the same as this buffer? I have tried to use `htmlize` and `htmlfontify`, but both have issues with the virtual spaces added by `org-indent-mode`.

[image: htmlize generated HTML export]

This is how it looks like by using `htmlize`. Note that the virtual spaces (i.e. text indentation) are missing.

Comment: I can't make sense of your question. Your second screenshot looks like the same org file without `org-indent-mode` being active.

Comment: @aadcg I want to make a HTML or PDF that looks exactly like the first screenshot. The second screenshot is the result of my failed attempt by using `htmlize`.

Comment: Define exactly.